# How would I calculate this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm working on a homework assignment and got stuck on this problem:

Let T be the transformation that first slides a point in $R^2$ to the y-axis along a path parallel to the line y = x and then scales the point by factor of 3.

Find the matrix B of T with respect to the basis { $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ , $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$}.

I tried setting up a relation between E1 and the transformation but got a zero matrix as the result. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What did you get for $T(e_1)$, where $e_1$ is the first element of the basis?

Comment: I got [0 0]^T because I thought the transformation would slide the vector to the origin and scale it by 3, which would still just be [0, 0]^T

Comment: $e_1$ doesn’t lie on the line $y=x$, so why do you think that it would slide to the origin?

Comment: Please do not remove the question when the question "is resolved". The proper thing to do is to accept (and preferably also upvote) the answer that you found most helpful, and leave the question as it is so that people in the future can benefit from reading both the answer and the question it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T$ sends the point $(a,b)$ to the point $(0,3(b-a))$, so we have
$$
T(2,1)=(0,-3)=-(2,1)+2(1,-1) \\
T(1,-1)=(0,-6)=-2(2,1)+4(1,-1)
$$
And the matrix representing $T$ with respect to the given basis is
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -2 \\
2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: That’s the transpose of the correct matrix.

Comment: @amd, the matrix is correct

Comment: Really? Let’s see: $B(1,0)^T = (-1,-2)^T$, which in the standard basis is $-(2,1)^T-2(1,-1)^T=(-4,1)^T\ne(0,-3)^T$. On the other hand $B^T(1,0)^T=(-1,2)^T$, which by your own calculations is $(0,-3)^T$ in the standard basis. Your $B$ would be correct were we working with _row_ vectors, but from the question it’s clear that we’re working with _column_ vectors.